Question regarding proof of second-order Taylor formula for scalar fields
The following theorem can be found in section 9.10 of Apostol's Calculus Vol. II (2nd edition).
Theorem: Let $f:S\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0.$ If the second order partial derivatives $D_i(D_j f)$ are continuous in $B(a,\varepsilon)$ then, for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a+y\in B(a,\varepsilon),$ it holds that $$f(a+y)-f(a)=\langle\nabla f(a),y\rangle+\frac{1}{2!}yH(a+cy)y^t,$$ where $0<c<1$.

I'm writing down the proof in my notebook but filling in the details omitted by Apostol as a way of justifying each step and checking my understanding.
First fix $y$ and define the function $r:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by the rule $u\mapsto a+uy$. Now, let $g:=(f\circ r)(u):[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.
In order to find $g'$ we apply the chain rule and we obtain
$$g'(u)=\langle\nabla f[r(u)],r'(u)\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^nD_jf(r(u))y_j.$$
So far so good, the problem comes next when Apostol claims that the second derivative of $g$ is:
$$g''(u)=\sum_{i=1}^nD_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n D_jf[r(u)]y_j\right)y_i\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n D_{ij}f[r(u)]y_iy_j.$$
My attempt to compute $g''$ is the following:
\begin{align*}
g''(u)&=\langle \nabla f[r(u)],r'(u)\rangle '&&\\
&=\langle \nabla(\nabla f[r(u)]),r'(u)\rangle +\langle \nabla f[r(u)],r''(u)\rangle &&\\
&=\langle \langle\nabla(\nabla f[r(u)]),r'(u)\rangle ,r'(u)\rangle +0,
\end{align*}
where I have used the product rule first and then the chain rule. The problem I have is that I don't see how the expression I found equals $$\sum_{i=1}^nD_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n D_jf[r(u)]y_j\right)y_i.$$
When I look at that sum, I interpret each term of the sum as the $i$-th partial derivative of $g'(u)$ multiplied by the $i$-th coordinate of $y$.
So, is the expression I found for $g''$ even correct in the first place? If so, how does it equal to the sum given by Apostol?

Anyone has any comments or input on this?

Very clumsy. $r'(u)$ is a complicated way of writing the vector $y,.$ Then your final expression for $g''(u)$ agrees with that of Apostol.

@KurtG. Ofc $r'(u)=y$ and $r''(u)=0$. My main problem occurred when I attempted to express the "inside" scalar product $\langle \nabla ^2 f[r(u)], r'(u)\rangle$ as a sum

That is exactly what Apostol is doing in a better notation. An even better notation would imho be to write $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\Bigg|_{r(u)}h(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$ for any function we are here partially differentiating because Apostol's notation $D_i$ might give the wrong impression that we differentiate w.r.t. $y_i,.$ You are overthinking this by far.
